# setup nginx ssl nodejs+express socket.io angularjs

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, socket.io

i have build nodejs+express on backend and angularjs on fronted and run under nginx. 
this my setup for nginx

```
  server {
      listen 82;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

      location / {
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
      }

  }
```

and this route 443 for ssl

```
 server {
      listen 443;
      ssl on;
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
      ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/config.com.ssl/ssl.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/config.com.ssl/ssl.key;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;

      location / {
          proxy_pass https://someIP:8085;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }


      location ~ ^/(scripts.*js|styles|images) {
          gzip_static on;
          expires 1y;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
          add_header ETag "";

          break;
      }
      location /socket.io {
          proxy_pass https://someIP:3001;
          #proxy_http_version 1.1;
          #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          #proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          #proxy_set_header Host $host;
          #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

      location /api {
          proxy_pass https://someIP:3001;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }   

      location /public {
          proxy_pass https://someIP:3001;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       } 
}
```

and on backend i setup server like this

```
   var app = require('../app');
   var debug = require('debug')('tlevi:server');
   var fs = require('fs');
   var http = require('http');
   var https = require('https')
   var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./configssl/ssl.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./configssl/ssl.crt')
  }
  /**
   * Get port from environment and store in Express.
   */

  var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
  app.set('port', port);

  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
   */

  //var server = http.createServer(app);
  var server = https.createServer(options, app);
  /**var server = https.createServer(app, options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n ssl');
  }).listen(3000);
  */
  var io = app.io;
  io.attach(server);

  /**
   * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
   */

  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
```

server run smooth like charm, but on client side got 502 bad gateway (but ssl run well). somethimes client can run but can akses API from client to server.

what i missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Wow late response: `listen 82;` should be `listen 80;`

Default http request port is 80. That would explain why ssl is working.